# Some questions about Create live Chat Application in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, chat, livechat

wanna create a Live Chat Application in asp.net (c#)
i have some questions about that.

1-what is best way? (fastest way - secure way - optimized way) for save chat data? in text file? in XML file? or in MS SQL Server?

2-How can i solve large number of user chat in one time?

3-how can i implement "user is writing..." in application?

4- how can i show new message to user? should i Ajax request in 1 Seconds and check if new message is sent and then show it? or you have better way?

5-how can i detect if chat is over? for example user close windows and leave the chat without click on "end chat button". how can detect that?

Best regards...

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a SignalR solution.

For more information:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: hi tnx for attention . but we must develop from base. not use plugin

Comment: Do you mean you have to reinvent the wheel? Why? It will never be as good as SignalR.